# reactjs and redux: How to implement filter text box for a rows of data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning reactj and redux. Somehow i managed to get data from api and display them in table. The table is shown below.

[image]

I want to add filter text box below each column header so that when i type text, it shows those values matching the results.

What is the flow using redux. Or any example

Comment: Please ,try , make attempt, encounter issues,then stackoverflow stackoverflow has a meaning!

Comment: if i have created an input element, where to pass the value of input

Comment: You can do it with redux or within your component state.
redux: 
Dispatch this value using your store. Handle this event in your reducer. in the render function filter based on this value.
Similar to this you can do with your inner state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just typed this up, its just for a general idea of how to filter data in your mapstate function. This is called computing derived data https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html and its good to use tools like Reselect for performance benefits. This isnt working code, but its just to give you an idea of how it is usually done so you dont get duplicate state in your reducers.

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  filterData = (event, column) => {
    this.props.someFilterAction(event.target.value, column)
  }
  renderItem = (item) => {
    return <someItemDiv searchAction={(e) => this.filterData(e, item.column) } />
  }
  render(){
    <div>
      { this.props.data.map(this.renderItem) }
    </div>
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const searchItem = state.searchData;
  // reselect is good for stuff like this
  const filteredData = state.tableData.filter(item => item[searchItem.column].text.indexOf(searchItem.input) !== -1 )
  // or some kind of search criteria you want
  return {
    data: filteredData,
    searchItem: state.searchData
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  someFilterAction: YourReduxActionCreator
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Table);

function YourReduxActionCreator(input, column) {
  return {
    type: FILTER_DATA,
    payload: {
      column,
      input,
    }
  }
}

function yourReducer() {
  switch(state, action) {
      case FILTER_DATA:
          return action.payload
      default:
          return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the layout

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just need to create 2 selectors.

The first one : getTableData() that get your whole table data from your store

Then getFilteredTableData() which will filter the result of getTableData() using the form values of your field (your keyword and the column).

The selector getFilteredTableData() should be the source of data for your table.

So as soon as your form change your table will be refiltered !

Comment: very helpful to start

Comment: If you need more info feel free to ask